# Default value of sla in airflow task

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x

I am trying to use `sla` with Airflow DAG. But I am not able to get the default value of `sla` anywhere in documentation (When SLA is not checked).

```
task2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id = "task_2",
    sla = timedelta(seconds=VAL),
    python_callable = dela,
    pool = 'monitoring_jobs_pool',
    provide_context = True,
    dag=dag
)
```

I am creating multiple DAGs with tasks like these where `sla` values is dependent on a variable, and most of the times this value (of VAL) fetched by another piece of code is 0, where I don't want to monitor SLA but at other places, this will be some value like 20, 50 or any other value to monitor. What should I set the default value of `sla` to skip the SLA check. Also would using a very large value to accomplish the same thing will have any effect on airflow performance. With 0 I thought the SLA check would be skipped, however task is visible in SLA miss UI even with `sla` value defined as 0. It's not feasible for me to miss "sla" keyword if `sla` is zero. Would appreciate any answers/suggestions to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for SLA is `None` (which is in the [BaseOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/models/baseoperator.html#BaseOperator))

Setting `VAL` to 0 should trigger an SLA straight away since it misses the SLA from the offset.

You could implement something like:

```
task2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id="task_2",
    sla=timedelta(seconds=VAL) if VAL > 0 else None,
    python_callable=dela,
    pool='monitoring_jobs_pool',
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

to skip the SLA if `VAL` is 0.